# How can I fix this MIME type error which is what I think the main problem is

Tags: javascript, vue.js, console

So I have a portfolio website that is using mostly vanilla Javascript. However, I just made an app in Vue, and cannot seem to properly link to the Vue app. Every time I click on the HREF to my Vue app, it gives me a MIME type error saying `'Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/static/css/app.8941a4b….css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.'` It also won't load anything onto the webpage. Any suggestions? I'm on Linux btw.

[image: This is the error message].

Comment: as for `it wont load anything onto the webpage` - you do realise you have a second error? a 404 (Not Found) error - there's something messed up with your paths, obviously the http server (apache?) is sending a html error page (text/html) when trying to access the .css

Comment: Fix the server to serve the CSS file with the right headers.